# why doesn't my window close when I press the escape key

Tags: python, pycharm

why doesn't my window close when I press the escape key:

```
import pygame

pygame.display.init()
pygame.display.set_mode(size=(500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("hi")
x = 1

while True:
    if pygame.key.get_mods() & pygame.K_ESCAPE:
        x = 2

if x == 2:
    pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Maybe you need to use break in while loop?

Answer (score 0):

You need an event-loop in your while-loop like so:

```
import pygame

pygame.display.init()
pygame.display.set_mode(size=(500, 500))
pygame.display.set_caption("hi")
x = 1

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # uses the small 'x' on the top right to close the window
            pygame.quit()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: # processes all the Keydown events
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE: # processes the Escape event (K_A would process the event that the key 'A' is hit
                x = 2

    if x == 2:
        pygame.quit()
    pygame.display.update()
```

I also added `pygame.display.update()`, which should normally be in your code.

Comment: If you want to check for other keys being hit, use if-statements in the `pygame.KEYDOWN` if-statement to check for `event.key == pygame.K_{insertKeyToBePressed}:`

Comment: I also highly recommend that you don't use `while True` for your game loop but rather use a boolean `run = True` and set it to `False` when your program is supposed to end. It is a lot cleaner than using `pygame.quit()` or `break`